# jpa Many to many with extra columns : column id cannot be null

Tags: spring, jpa

I'm trying to save a Entity with relationship many to many with extra column but I've received an error

Item :

```
import java.util.Set;

import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;

@Entity
public class Item {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Integer id ;
private String name ;
private String brand ;
private String category ;
private Double unitPrice ;
private Double weight ;
private String manufacturer ;
private String description ;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "item", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)

private Set<ItemInventory> itemInventories;

public Integer getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Integer id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getBrand() {
    return brand;
}

public void setBrand(String brand) {
    this.brand = brand;
}

public String getCategory() {
    return category;
}

public void setCategory(String category) {
    this.category = category;
}

public Double getUnitPrice() {
    return unitPrice;
}

public void setUnitPrice(Double unitPrice) {
    this.unitPrice = unitPrice;
}

public Double getWeight() {
    return weight;
}

public void setWeight(Double weight) {
    this.weight = weight;
}

public String getManufacturer() {
    return manufacturer;
}

public void setManufacturer(String manufacturer) {
    this.manufacturer = manufacturer;
}

public String getDescription() {
    return description;
}

public void setDescription(String description) {
    this.description = description;
}


public Item() {
    super();
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

public Set<ItemInventory> getItemInventories() {
    return itemInventories;
}

public void setItemInventories(Set<ItemInventory> itemInventories) {
    this.itemInventories = itemInventories;
}

public Item(Integer id, String name, String brand, String category, Double unitPrice, Double weight,
        String manufacturer, String description, Set<ItemInventory> itemInventories) {
    super();
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    this.brand = brand;
    this.category = category;
    this.unitPrice = unitPrice;
    this.weight = weight;
    this.manufacturer = manufacturer;
    this.description = description;
    this.itemInventories = itemInventories;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Item [id=" + id + "]";
}
}
```

Inventory :

```
import java.util.Set;

import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;

@Entity
public class Inventory {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Integer id;
private String address ;
private String phone ;
@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Inventory [id=" + id + "]";
}



private String gps_coordinates ;


@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "company_id")
private Company company ;


@OneToMany(mappedBy = "inventory", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
private Set<ItemInventory> itemInventories;



public Integer getId() {
    return id;
}



public void setId(Integer id) {
    this.id = id;
}



public String getAddress() {
    return address;
}



public void setAddress(String address) {
    this.address = address;
}



public String getPhone() {
    return phone;
}



public void setPhone(String phone) {
    this.phone = phone;
}



public String getGps_coordinates() {
    return gps_coordinates;
}



public void setGps_coordinates(String gps_coordinates) {
    this.gps_coordinates = gps_coordinates;
}











public Set<ItemInventory> getItemInventories() {
    return itemInventories;
}



public void setItemInventories(Set<ItemInventory> itemInventories) {
    this.itemInventories = itemInventories;
}








public Company getCompany() {
    return company;
}



public void setCompany(Company company) {
    this.company = company;
}









public Inventory(Integer id, String address, String phone, String gps_coordinates, Company company,
        Set<ItemInventory> itemInventories) {
    super();
    this.id = id;
    this.address = address;
    this.phone = phone;
    this.gps_coordinates = gps_coordinates;
    this.company = company;
    this.itemInventories = itemInventories;
}



public Inventory() {
    super();
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}






}
```

ItemInventory :

```
import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;

import org.hibernate.annotations.NotFound;
import org.hibernate.annotations.NotFoundAction;

@Entity
@Table(name = "item_inventory")

public class ItemInventory implements Serializable {

@Id
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "item_id")
private Item item ;
@Id
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "inventory_id")

private Inventory inventory ;


private Long quantity ;



public Item getItem() {
    return item;
}
public void setItem(Item item) {
    this.item = item;
}


public Inventory getInventory() {
    return inventory;
}
public void setInventory(Inventory inventory) {
    this.inventory = inventory;
}

@Column(name = "quantity")
public Long getQuantity() {
    return quantity;
}
public void setQuantity(Long quantity) {
    this.quantity = quantity;
}
public ItemInventory(Item item, Inventory inventory, Long quantity) {
    super();
    this.item = item;
    this.inventory = inventory;
    this.quantity = quantity;
}
public ItemInventory() {
    super();
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}
@Override
public String toString() {
    return "ItemInventory [item=" + item + ", inventory=" + inventory + ", quantity=" + quantity + "]";
}




}
```

The stack trace :

> com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException:
>   Column 'item_id' cannot be null   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_112]   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_112]   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown
>   Source) ~[na:1.8.0_112]   at
>   java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_112]   at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:425)
>   ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.43.jar:5.1.43]     at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:408)
>   ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.43.jar:5.1.43]     at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:935)
>   ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.43.jar:5.1.43]     at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3973)
>   ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.43.jar:5.1.43]     at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3909)
>   ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.43.jar:5.1.43]     at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2527)
>   ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.43.jar:5.1.43]     at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2680)
>   ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.43.jar:5.1.43]     at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2494)
>   ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.43.jar:5.1.43]     at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:1858)
>   ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.43.jar:5.1.43]     at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2079)
>   ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.43.jar:5.1.43]     at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2013)
>   ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.43.jar:5.1.43]     at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeLargeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:5104)
>   ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.43.jar:5.1.43]     at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:1998)
>   ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.43.jar:5.1.43]     at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_112]   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_112]   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_112]   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_112]   at
>   org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.StatementFacade$StatementProxy.invoke(StatementFacade.java:114)
>   ~[tomcat-jdbc-8.5.16.jar:na]  at
>   com.sun.proxy.$Proxy104.executeUpdate(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]    at
>   org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:204)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]   at
>   org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.NonBatchingBatch.addToBatch(NonBatchingBatch.java:45)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]   at
>   org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2949)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]   at
>   org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3449)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]   at
>   org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityInsertAction.execute(EntityInsertAction.java:89)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]   at
>   org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:582)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]   at
>   org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:456)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]   at
>   org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:337)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]   at
>   org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:39)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]   at
>   org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1282)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]   at
>   org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:465)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]   at
>   org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flushBeforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:2963)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]   at
>   org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:2339)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]   at
>   org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcCoordinatorImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(JdbcCoordinatorImpl.java:485)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]   at
>   org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.beforeCompletionCallback(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:147)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]   at
>   org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.access$100(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:38)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]   at
>   org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl$TransactionDriverControlImpl.commit(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:231)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]   at
>   org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:65)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]   at
>   org.hibernate.jpa.internal.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:61)
>   ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]  at
>   org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:517)
>   ~[spring-orm-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:761)
>   ~[spring-tx-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:730)
>   ~[spring-tx-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:504)
>   ~[spring-tx-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:292)
>   ~[spring-tx-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
>   ~[spring-tx-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
>   ~[spring-aop-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:136)
>   ~[spring-tx-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
>   ~[spring-aop-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:133)
>   ~[spring-data-jpa-1.11.6.RELEASE.jar:na]  at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
>   ~[spring-aop-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
>   ~[spring-aop-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
>   ~[spring-aop-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.invoke(SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.java:57)
>   ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.6.RELEASE.jar:na]  at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
>   ~[spring-aop-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213)
>   ~[spring-aop-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]   at
>   com.sun.proxy.$Proxy92.save(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]  at
>   com.inconso.companyManagement.ItemController.addItem(ItemController.java:38)
>   ~[classes/:na]    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native
>   Method) ~[na:1.8.0_112]   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_112]   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_112]   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_112]   at
>   org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205)
>   ~[spring-web-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:133)
>   ~[spring-web-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:97)
>   ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827)
>   ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738)
>   ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
>   ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:967)
>   ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:901)
>   ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
>   ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:872)
>   ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]    at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:661)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]    at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
>   ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]    at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]    at
>   org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]    at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99)
>   ~[spring-web-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>   ~[spring-web-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]    at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:105)
>   ~[spring-web-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>   ~[spring-web-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]    at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:81)
>   ~[spring-web-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>   ~[spring-web-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]    at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197)
>   ~[spring-web-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>   ~[spring-web-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:478)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:80)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]     at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:799)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]     at
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]     at
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1455)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
>   [na:1.8.0_112]    at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
>   [na:1.8.0_112]    at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]     at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown
>   Source) [na:1.8.0_112]

Here is my controller :

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.inconso.models.Inventory;
import com.inconso.models.Item;
import com.inconso.models.ItemInventory;
import com.inconso.repositories.InventoryRepository;
import com.inconso.repositories.ItemRepository;

@RestController
public class ItemController {
    @Autowired
    private ItemRepository itemRepos ;
    @Autowired
    private InventoryRepository inventoryRepos ;
    @RequestMapping(value = "itemInventory/add/{company}", method = RequestMethod.POST)

        public Object addItem(@RequestBody ItemInventory itemInventory)  {

        Item item = itemRepos.findOne(itemInventory.getItem().getId()) ;
        // still add stuff here in case item not found
        Inventory inventory = inventoryRepos.findOne(itemInventory.getInventory().getId()) ;
        // still add stuff here if inventory not found

        itemInventory.setInventory(inventory);
        itemInventory.setItem(item);


        item.getItemInventories().add(itemInventory) ;
        inventory.getItemInventories().add(itemInventory) ;
        System.out.println("-------"+itemInventory.getItem()+"---------");

        itemRepos.save(item) ;







        return "Item added" ;
      }





}
```

Comment: yes both set, I don't understand what you mean ?

Comment: Then try to change the GeneratedValue.AUTO to IDENTITY

Comment: I changed it, still same error

Comment: And both sides do have the references set? Item, ItemInventory and Inventory having the collections and the reference set?

Comment: yes, I did the same thing as this tutorial : https://hellokoding.com/jpa-many-to-many-extra-columns-relationship-mapping-example-with-spring-boot-maven-and-mysql/

Comment: And this tutorial runs without errors?

Comment: I didn't try it, coz I thought they got it right (first in google search)

Comment: I've tried the example app and it work. So if you did it exactly the same why yours should work too. Please check again.

Comment: I added the controller that I use, please check it

Comment: I can't see something that is not correct. Can you debug and check if everything is ok?

Comment: I removed this line : `item.getItemInventories().add(itemInventory) ;` and it worked

Answer (score 1):

I removed this line

```
item.getItemInventories().add(itemInventory) ;
```

and it worked, I think because inventory is the owner of the realtionship, so we should add the itemInventory object to inventory only not both (item and inventory)